# JavaFX Autosizing two or more VBoxes side-by-side in an HBox

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have two VBoxes side-by-side inside an HBox.  The HBox width can be changed by the user.

How can I make the VBoxes automatically resize so that they always fill the HBox?

More specifically:
How would I make each VBox always be 50% of the width of the HBox?  And, how would I make them 75% and 25%?

If I had 3 VBoxes inside the HBox, how could I make them to be 30%, 40%, and 30% of the width of the HBox?

Comment: You should look into using [column constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/ColumnConstraints.html)

Comment: Post your`FXML` file. Explain what you have, and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, it seems like you are trying to ask more than one question per thread. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: If dynamically user configurable, use a [`SplitPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html) instead of a `HBox`, otherwise use a [`GridPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html) as demonstrated in the duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you!  GridPane is what I was looking for